# Why is the docker container larger than it actually is?

Tags: docker, gitlab

I enter `# docker ps -s` and it shows:

```
a658   gitlab/gitlab-ce:15.0.2-ce.0   ...   2.62MB (virtual 2.49GB)
```

But, when I enter `# du -h /var/lib/docker/containers/ --max-depth=1` it shows:

```
20G     /var/lib/docker/containers/a658
```

Gitlab container by default mounts /srv folder, there is a gitlab database, but it also weighs a little:

```
# du -h /srv/gitlab/ --max-depth=1
184K    /srv/gitlab/config
428M    /srv/gitlab/logs
2.8G    /srv/gitlab/data
3.2G    /srv/gitlab/
```

What could it be? This worries me very much, because the disk space of the host system is running out, and I cannot figure out what exactly is clogging all the space and where to look for it. At first I thought these were gitlab logs, but the corresponding folders weigh incomparably little. How can I check this and clean up the excess?

Going inside the container, I see that it also weighs very little:

```
# docker exec -it a658 bash
# du -h / --max-depth=1 | sort -h

0       /boot
0       /home
0       /media
0       /mnt
0       /proc
0       /srv
0       /sys
4.0K    /tmp
12K     /root
16K     /run
28K     /assets
1.5M    /etc
7.7M    /dev
90M     /usr
2.5G    /opt
3.2G    /var
5.7G    /
```

P.S. If it matters, host system on CentOS 7

I tried to find similar questions, but their answers does not helped me.

Comment: Mountpoints, mountpoints everywhere. What are the volumes mounted in the container? Do you think `du /var/lib/docker/containers/` follows the mountpoints? What is the output of `du --one-file-system`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I thought that if you go into the container, it will also show the size of all mount points. At the moment, a point /srv from the host system is mounted inside the container (I indicated this in the question, and this is according to the official gitlab documentation)

Comment: Yes, and "size of all mount points" != size of the container. `I indicated this in the question` Please post the output of `mount` from inside the container. Please inspect `docker inspect` of the container and image. I see `"Volumes": {
                "/etc/gitlab": {},
                "/var/log/gitlab": {},
                "/var/opt/gitlab": {}
            }` which I think gives at least 3 mountpoints.